# MobileFirst is_connected, is_disconnected events do not work

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-runtime

I'm using MobileFirst 7 to develop a hybrid Windows8 + iPad app.

The event `WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED` works fine if I start my app with server down, but if I start app with server up (online) then I stop server the event is not risen.

This happens in both Windows8 and iOS (ipad) environments.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277550/ibm-mobilefirst-7-0-working-offline-sample-application-not-working

Answer (score 1):

A regression was introduced in MFPF 7.0 causing the WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED and WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED events to fail (APAR PI38012). It was fixed in a subsequent iFix release.

- If you are using the Developer Edition then make sure you are using the latest build in Eclipse > Help > Check for updates.
- If you're using the Consumer or Enterprise Editions then get the latest iFix from IBM Fix Central website.

The date of the fix should be from 2015-04-08 or later.